# jQuery 1.7 is *still* returning the event.layerX and event.layerY error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, webkit, jquery-1.7

What am I doing wrong? Am I misunderstanding the problem or is it something else entirely?

On my page I was using jQuery 1.6.4 from the Google CDN. This would, of course, generate the error:

> event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.

[I read here](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/) that jQuery 1.7 removed this issue. However, after updating my application to 1.7, I'm still seeing it. I'm using the Microsoft CDN until Google put the link up.

Things I've tried before posting this:

- Clearing the browser cache
- Changing back to jQuery 1.6.4 (still happens - obviously)
- Using jQuery 1.7-specific code to make sure 1.7 is actually being loaded - `.on()` works fine when I use 1.7 but obviously gives undefined errors with 1.6.4 - I thought this should prove 1.7 is actually running
- Commenting out and removing all other Javascript from my application - everything except for jQuery 1.7. Still triggers the error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Worked it out - it wasn't immediately obvious either, but posting this here for anyone who gets tripped up by this in future:

**It was a Chrome Extension that used an old version of jQuery causing the issue**. Disabling all Extensions and re-enabling one at a time helped me find the perpetrator. Hope this helps for anyone else with this issue in the future!

Comment: thanks, good catch! Loading the page in Incognito mode will do it as well, unless the plugins are enabled there too.

Comment: Hi Jack, which Chrome Extension was it? (Mine looks to be the 1Password Extension)...

Comment: Thanks! @TomBates For me, it was the HoverZoom extension.

Comment: @TomBates I am using the 1Password Extension but it didn't turn out to be that - maybe because I am using Chrome Dev or something... For me, it was FastestChrome. Although I'll bet there are hundreds of extensions out there that could affect this.

Comment: AdBlock 2.4.29 seems to be causing it for me, if that helps anyone. I went ahead and disabled it to remedy the problem.

Comment: My problem was with a Codec extension I had installed in Chrome. Disabling it fixed the issue.